# Way to check if the variable is value of something

Tags: c, variables, if-statement

is there any way how to check if the variable equals some value faster way than doing if statement `( m == value1 || m == value2 || m == value3...)` I tried `if m == ( value1 || value2 || ...)` but it works only for the first value. Here's an example, it returns true for 1 but not for 5 and the rest. I really appreciate all suggestions. TY!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int m;
    scanf("%i", &m);
    if(m == (1 || 5 || 7 ||  8 || 11 || 20)){
    printf("TRUE\n");
    }
    else {
    printf("FALSE\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `m == (1 || 5 || 7 ||  8 || 11 || 20)` doesn't do what you think it does....

Comment: this is a c++ dupe but exactly the same question (and answers)

Comment: I am sorry. I haven't been lookin in c++ tag.

Comment: don't be sorry. the question with the C tag didn't exist. Some solutions in the duplicate link don't apply due to C++, others apply perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator performs a logical OR between its two operands.  It evaluates to 1 if either operand is non-zero.  In the case of `1 || 5` This evaluates to 1 because at least one operand is non-zero.  This evaluation continues on for each successive `||` operator.

So the whole expression `(1 || 5 || 7 ||  8 || 11 || 20)` is equal to 1.

Your original check is the proper way to do this.  If you want something a bit less repetitive, you could do this with a `switch` statement with fallthrough cases:

```
switch (m) {
case 1:
case 5:
case 7:
case 8:
case 11:
case 20:
    printf("true\n");
    break;
default:
    printf("false\n");
    break;
}
```

Comment: In general case it is not _faster way_. Just less keypresses but execution time the same.

Comment: Oh this looks nice, I didn't know that you don't have to write code for each case. Thanks!

Comment: @Real with a good compiler, this approach is fastest.  With a weak compiler, better to seek a good optimizing compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`if(m == (1 || 5 || 7 ||  8 || 11 || 20))` actually doesn't do what you think it does.  First it computes the result of `(1 || 5 || 7 ||  8 || 11 || 20)` which is `true (1)`.  Then it compares `m` to that result.  So this only works when `m` is 1.  An easier way to do this is a switch statement:

```
switch(m) {
case 1:
  // do something
  break; // don't forget this
case 2:
  // do something
  break;
default:
  // do something when it's not any of the numbers you expect
  break;
}
```

In your case, since you want to do the same thing for all those number, just omit `break;` between case statements and they will all get executed:

```
switch(m) {
case 1:
case 2:
  // do something (when it's 1 or 2)
  break;
default:
  // do something when it's not any of the numbers you expect
  break;
}
```